# Master page não carrega em ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Minha master page não carrega no ASP.NET. Sei porque ela não carrega, não sei como resolver. A master page está em uma pasta atráz da pagina "isaque.aspx".
Código :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="isaque.aspx.cs" Inherits="isaque"MasterPageFile="../CommunityMasterPage.master"%>
```

Aqui uma print:

[image: Print]

Comment: faz um teste, ve se isso aqui da certo: `MasterPageFile="~/Community/CommunityMasterPage.master"`, só pra exclarecer, depois do `~` tem que colocar o caminho completo da pasta principal do sistema até a master page. Exemplo, se minha master fica no caminho `PastaRaizDoSistema/Pasta1/Pasta2/MinhaMasterPage.master` eu tenho que colocar `~/Pasta1/Pasta2/MinhaMasterPage.master`, faz o teste

Comment: funcionou, obrigado!

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! Eu publiquei como resposta aqui, se puder dar um upvote eu agradeço! Abraço, e caso precise de algo estou a disposição!

Comment: Adoraria votar, mas tenho menos que 15 de reputação, portanto não posso votar.

Comment: Sem problemas cara! Abraço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para corrigir este problema, basta adicionar o caminho para a master page desta forma:

`MasterPageFile="~/Community/CommunityMasterPage.master`

Só pra exclarecer, depois do `~` tem que colocar o caminho completo da pasta principal do sistema até a master page.

Exemplo, se minha master fica no caminho `PastaRaizDoSistema/Pasta1/Pasta2/MinhaMasterPage.master` eu tenho que colocar `~/Pasta1/Pasta2/MinhaMasterPage.master`, desta forma o sistema sempre vai pegar o caminho absoluto para o arquivo da master page.

Espero ter ajudado, abraço!